# How do I identify and compare which cell was clicked on a grid JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

sorry that the post is a bit long its just to be very clear about what im need.
I'm making a Board 8x8.
i did it like using loop.
works perfect.

```
// Create a center tag to center all the elements
        var center = document.createElement('center');
        var count = 1;
        // Create a table element
        var ChessTable = document.createElement('table');
        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

            // Create a row
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {

                // Create a cell
                var td = document.createElement('td');

                // If the sum of cell coordinates is even
                // then color the cell white
                if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {

                    // Create a class attribute for all white cells
                    td.setAttribute('class', 'cell whitecell');
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                   // td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`Cell I${i}/J${j}`));
                }

                // If the sum of cell coordinates is odd then
                // color the cell black
                else {

                    // Create a class attribute for all black cells
                    td.setAttribute('class', 'cell blackcell');

                    // Append the cell to its row
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                   // td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`Cell I${i}/J${j}`));
                    
                }
            }

            // Append the row
            ChessTable.appendChild(tr);
        }
        center.appendChild(ChessTable);

        // Modifying table attribute properties
        ChessTable.setAttribute('cellspacing', '0');
        ChessTable.setAttribute('width', '270px');
        document.body.appendChild(center);
        console.log(ChessTable);
```

now i needed to make option that if you click on certain cell the cell changing color. works perfect too.

```
 function respondToClick(event)
    {
        if (event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'td') {
            event.target.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
    }        ChessTable.addEventListener("click", respondToClick);
```

know i needed to random cells and then collor then. i did it to and works great, i did it using random function from 0-63, then convert the numbers to base 8, because i wanted to compare each cell to the row and column, then split the numbers to know each row and column.

```
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max)
        {
            return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
        }
    //random numbers
    var a = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        a[j] = getRandomArbitrary(0, 64)           
    }
    console.log(a)      
    var b = [];
    b = a;
    //convert to base 8
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
       b[j]=b[j].toString(8);
    }

    console.log(b);
    const cells = []

    //seperate the digidt for board

    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        b[j] = b[j].toString(8);
        var digits = b[j].toString().split('');
        var realDigits = digits.map(Number)
        console.log(realDigits);

        // coloring the random numbers
        if (realDigits[1] != null) {
             cells[j] = ChessTable.rows[realDigits[0]].cells[realDigits[1]];
            cells[j].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        }
        else {
            cells[j] = ChessTable.rows[0].cells[realDigits[0]];
            cells[j].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        }
    }
```

that`s work great too.

**Now the last problem** that i have is that i need to do this.
first the computer need to random the cells, but don`t need to show them yet, when there is click in the mouse then the user need to know if the click was on cell that the computer chose randomly.

so i added did this to the `respondToClick` function.

```
 function respondToClick(event, cells)
        {
            if (event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'td')
            {
                event.target.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                if (event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == cells[0]) {
                    alert("correct")
                }
            }
         }
```

in cells i have the "place of the cells(i added a photo)
(cells[0] is just for testing, i can use loop there for each click to go over all the cells)

so when i compare the event to the cells[0], i`m getting error. what im missing here?[image: the error]

Comment: display the value of `event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase()` and the value of `cells[0]` ... are they something that you can compare?

Comment: @jsotola umm.. im getting td and not the cell... how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

First, let's organize your code better, so it is easier to work with the board.

You are currently making the board using a table, which I don't recommend. Instead, it would be better to use a `<div>`.

Also, you are using a two-dimensional array, that isn't needed, and can sometimes overcomplicate the code.

I would recommend using a one dimensional array instead.

```
function makeBoard(height, width, init_callback){
    return Array(height*width).fill(0).map(init_callback);
}
```

Make board will create an array of the length height * width, and populate it using the callback function.

The callback would look something like this:

```
function initCell(){
    const cell = document.createElement("div");
    // make changes to cell
    cell.classList.add("cell")
    return cell
}
```

You can then add the grid to your HTML easily, by using `.append()`.

```
//  <div id="board" />
const board = document.querySelector("#board");

const pieces = makeBoard(8, 9, initCell);

// append can take multiple elements. Making it easy to add our elements by de-structering our array.
board.append(...pieces);
```

Now, to style the board, we don't need to use JavaScript. CSS is very powerful and can easily handle it for us.

```css
.cell {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: white;
}

.cell:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: brown;
}

.cell:nth-child(9n+1){
  display: none;
}

#board {
  height:  320px;
  width: 320px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 40px);
}
```

If you look at the precious JS and CSS, our grid is actually 8x9 and not 8x8. This is because, to easily create a chessboard pattern, we are creating a 8x9 board and then removing the 9th cell of each row, to create the chessboard.

Now to add the click events, it's relatively easy.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".cell").forEach(cell => {
    cell.addEventListener("click", cellClickHandler)
});
```

That code will set the `onClick` event on the cells to the `cellClickHandler` function.

To change the bg-color, when clicked, it would look like this:

```
function cellClickHandler(e){
    e.target.classList.toggle("green")
}
```

Now here's a runnable version, to see what we have so far:

```js
function makeBoard(height, width, init_callback){
    return Array(height*width).fill(0).map(init_callback)
}

function initCell(){
    const cell = document.createElement("div");
    // make changes to cell
    cell.classList.add("cell");
    return cell
}

//  <div id="board" />
const board = document.querySelector("#board");

const pieces = makeBoard(8, 9, initCell);
board.append(...pieces);

document.querySelectorAll(".cell").forEach(cell => {
    cell.addEventListener("click", cellClickHandler)
});

function cellClickHandler(e){
    e.target.classList.toggle("green")
}
```

```css
.cell {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: white;
}

.cell:nth-child(odd){
  background-color: brown;
}

.cell:nth-child(9n+1){
  display: none;
  border: none;
}

.green {
  background-color: green !important;
}

#board {
  height:  320px;
  width: 320px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 40px);
}
```

```html
<div id="board" />
```

Comment: Thanks you, very clean code, tho the problem still remain lol, how can  i compare the cells which the computer chose and i chose?

Comment: I will update my answer later today, with the rest of the code. Just to be sure, do you want a random cell to be picked, and if the user clicks it, it changes the color,l depending on if it was right or not.

Comment: i want to random 5 numbers, and they need to be invisible from the user, when the user click on certain cell then the computer will tell him if he mange to guess the right cell or not, and the user have 5 guests.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `bind` or a closure to pass the cells parameter to the handler.

```
const chessTableClickHandler = respondToClick.bind(null, cells);

ChessTable.addEventListener("click", chessTableClickHandler);

function respondToClick(cells, event)
        {
            if (event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'td')
            {
                event.target.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                if (event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == cells[0]) {
                    alert("correct")
                }
            }
         }
```

Comment: THanks you very much, i just notice  that when i "event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase()" im getting "td" and not the cell itself, do you know how i can chaged this?